# Running Django on Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I am learning Django and has made a simple app. I was thinking of deploying that app to Google AppEngine.

What is the easiest way to do it (i.e. the one which involves changing as little code as possible)?

What is the best way to do it (i.e. the one which supports most of Django's features)?

I know similar questions have been asked here but none of the questions were asked after Nov 2010 (http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django.html)?

Comment: Google told you on the page you linked - [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel) & [google's tutorial](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django-nonrel.html). Furthermore, there are plenty of questions and answers on django and google-appengine since Nov 2010

Comment: Beyond Google's tutorial / suggestions, 'best' is really up to you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to learn full django with Google App Engine the project to recommend is [www.allbuttonspressed.com](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com)
It implements full django with Google App Engine. If you want to learn the basics I suggest starting with SDK 1.6 and python 2.7 so that you realize that upgrading from python 2.6 to 2.7 without manually copying in the django you use will break django dependance.

I used much django with app engine but I'm getting out in favor of Jinja2 for template engine and WTForms for forms since with python 2.7 the google.db.djangoforms is not available so for more advanced stuff than basic forms you would want a form framework and WTForms seems OK though I didn't use all of it yet.

I hope some of these opinions from me be relevant.

Comment: allbuttonspressed is just the website, the projects are called django-nonrel and djangoappengine.

Comment: Please keep in mind that you won't be able you to use some native Django functionality like ManyToMany relationships or Multi-Table inheritance if you decide to use django-nonrel.

Comment: Yes, which functionality are you after when you install full django? Is it the special tags or more advanced form management? I've seen many developers more positive to the combination Jinja2 + WTForms compared to the large procedure of adding entire django and for which functionality?